# I forgot to write the name on the check

Tags: check

I forgot to write the name on the check, but I signed and put the numbers. Is the bank going to accept this check?

Comment: You forgot to write the Pay to name when you wrote the check? or you got a check and while encashing, you signed and did not write your name?

Comment: Consider it like cash. If you don't trust the people who are going to have their hands on it, you should cancel it. It might cost you a small fee.

Answer (score 9):

If you forgot to put the name on the "pay to the order of" line then anybody who gets their hands on the check can add their name to the check and deposit it at their bank into their account.

If it goes to the correct person they will have an easy time making sure that the check is made out correctly. They don't have to worry about that picky teller who doesn't know what to do with a check made out to Billy Smith and a drivers license for Xavier William Smith.

On the other hand... a criminal will also be able to make sure it is processed exactly the way they want it.

If I made it out to a small business or a person I would let them know. You might not have a choice but to wait and see what happens if it was sent to a large business, the payment processing center could be a long way from where you will be calling.